run_in_executor times out but completes process
I have a google upload that happens concurrently using asyncio run_in_executor() method. It uploads (2) files to google drive. Sometimes it returns a TimeoutError: The read operation timed out, but it completes the upload. The timeoutError comes from the first file added to the pool.
What I think is happenings is that when the first file upload is completed and it's waiting on the second file to upload, it times out. Then the second file finishes without error then the error is thrown.
Is that correct" If so, how do I keep that first thread from throwing an error while waiting on the second thread to return? Or is there a better way to handle concurrent uploads?
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    await loop.run_in_executor(pool, _perform_upload,
                               file_metadata, media
                               )

def _perform_upload(file_metadata, media):
    drive = build_g_drive_serivce()
    drive.files().create(uploadType='resumable',
                         body=file_metadata,
                         media_body=media,
                         supportsAllDrives=True
                         ).execute()

def build_g_drive_service():
    creds = authenticated_creds
    drive = build(CONSTANTS.G_DRIVE,
                  CONSTANTS.G_DRIVE_VERSION,
                  credentials=creds,
                  cache_discovery=False
    )


Is this the code uploading both files?

yes, it's within a for loop that sets up the metadata and media (as MediaFileUpload object) for the google drive upload call.
